# Observable make request multiple times and collect response together

Tags: rxjs, observable, redux-observable

In database I have 19 users.
In my API, I can get only 5 results in one call.

If I want to get all them, I need to do request 4 times, each time to get 5 users. With `start` query I will change from which position I want new users to get.

I'm trying to do it in RxJS together with redux-observable.
I have some idea, but maybe my approach is imperative, and RxJS is opposite ideology.

```js
      // get users from API and `pipe` them helps me to see actual data and to count length of array
     function getUsers(position = 0) {
        return ajax.getJSON(`${API}/users?_start=${position}&_limit=5`).
            pipe(map(({data}) => ({responseLength: data.length, data})))
    }

// here when I got response if array.lenght is equal to 5, I know that I need to do fetch of data again.
// Problem is encountered here: if I do recursion after doing I will get only last result, not both of them, 
// if I put my previous result into array, and then recursion result again push in array it become too complicated after 
// in userFetchEpic to manipulate with this data
    function count(data) {
        return data.pipe(
            map(item => {
                if (item.responseLength === 5) {
                    count(getUsers(5));
                }
                return {type: "TEST" , item}
            })
        )
    }

    function userFetchEpic(action$) {
        return action$
            .pipe(
                ofType(USER_FETCH),
                mergeMap(() => {
                    return count(getUsers()).pipe(
                        map(i => i)
                    )
                })
            );
    }
```

My code is here just to show what was my way of thinking.

Main problem is in recursion how to save all values together, if I save values in array.
Then I need to loop through array of observables and that sounds complicated in my head. :)

Probably this problem have much easier and better solution.

Comment: You could use [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) !?

Answer (score 0):

#### 19 Users with 4 concurrent calls

I've re-arranged your get-users function to generate 4 Ajax calls, run them all concurrently, then flatten the result into one array. This should get you all 19 users in a single array.

```
function getUsers() {
  return forkJoin(
    [0,5,10,15].map(position => 
      ajax.getJSON(`${API}/users?_start=${position}&_limit=5`)
    )
  ).pipe(
    map(resArray => resArray.flatMap(res => res.data))
  )
}

function userFetchEpic(action$) {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(USER_FETCH),
    mergeMap(_ => getUsers())
  );
}
```

#### Generalize: Recursively get users

This, again, will return all 19 users, but this time you don't need to know that you have 19 users ahead of time. On the other hand, this makes all its calls in sequence, so I would expect it to be slower.

You'll notice this one is done recursively. You are creating a call stack this way, but so long as you don't have millions of users, it shouldn't be a problem.

```
function getUsers(position = 0) {
  return ajax.getJSON(`${API}/users?_start=${position}&_limit=5`).pipe(
    switchMap(({data}) => 
      data.length < 5 ?
      of(data) :
      getUsers(position + 5).pipe(
        map(recursiveData => data.concat(recursiveData))
      )
    })
  );
}
```